# Cannot use some Matlab MPC Toolbox functions

Tags: matlab, toolbox, mpc

I'm trying to use for example `setoutdist` Matlab function from the MPC Toolbox (I'm using Matlab R2013a on Windows 8.1). As a response I'm receiving:

```
    Undefined function 'setoutdist' for input arguments of type 'ss'.
```

I am able to get help about this function using `help setoutdist`. When I'm typing the function name and left parenthesis I'm receiving prompt with list of the arguments. When I'm using `which setoutdist -all` I'm receiving proper output:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\mpc\mpc\@mpc\setoutdist.m  % mpc method code here
```

But the function doesn't work even in default Matlab path, so I don't think it is shadowed.
The same is with the other functions, for example `setindist`, `setestim`, `mpc_struct`, etc. but `mpc`, `mpcstate` and `mpcmove` functions works correctly.

I was trying: `clear all`, `clear classess`, `rehash toolbox`, `rehash pathreset`, `rehash toolboxreset`, restoring default paths using `pathtool`. I've blocked the antivirus and added exeptions to it's list. I've even reinstalled my Matlab, nothing helped.

Maybe this is significant: when I'm trying to edit the `setoutdist.m` I'm receiving message that access is denied.

I will extremly appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `setoutdist`? The correct syntax is one of the three (see [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ref/setoutdist.html) - for R2014b):

```
setoutdist(MPCobj,'integrators')
setoutdist(MPCobj,'remove',channels)
setoutdist(MPCobj,'model',model)
```

where `MPCobj` is a Model Predictive Controller object, created for example with the `mpc` function. It looks like from the error message that you are calling the function with a state-space object, which is not allowed (I'm guessing).

Comment: Stupid me... I did something like this: 'setoutdist(MatlMPCon.MatlabMpcObject, 'model', outDistModel);' where the 'outDistModel' was correct, but property of my own class 'MatlMPCon.MatlabMpcObject' was not initialized yet... Anyway, thank you for prompt :)